# Couldn't open file /packages/repodata/repomd.xml

Tags: mongodb

I am using Redhat Linux server and trying to install the MongoDB on it.

I am following steps given in the link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

**Step 1**: Create a /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.0.repo file so that you can install MongoDB directly, using yum.

```
sudo nano /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.0.repo
```

**Step 2**: Copy and paste below code in the newly created file.

```
[mongodb-org-4.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc
```

**Step 3**: To install a specific release of MongoDB, specify each component package individually and append the version number to the package name, as in the following example:

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```

After all this I am getting an error given below:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
file:///packages/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /packages/repodata/repomd.xml"
Trying other mirror.`


One of the configured repositories failed (local),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only 
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:`

 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
        yum --disablerepo=localrepo ...

 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable localrepo
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=localrepo

 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=localrepo.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from localrepo: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
file:///packages/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /packages/repodata/repomd.xml"
```

Server OS

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.3 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="7.3"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.3:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.3
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.3"
```

I already followed steps below but these are not working in my case:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.0.repo

sudo yum clean all
```

How could i resolve this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should check with **baseurl** in /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.0.repo file. we can also change the releaseserver version in baseurl.

Here is my /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.0.repo file

```
[mongodb-org-4.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message it looks like you had a nameserver problem, which can involve a variety of solutions as this [answer from redhat.com](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1164243) describes. My `mongodb-org-4.0.repo` file looks just like yours except with version 4.4 and everything worked fine. Well not at first that's how I found this post, but my problem was a blank space I accidentally inserted at the end of the `mongodb-org-4.4.repo` file.

I found this [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109585/yum-update-fails-error-cannot-retrieve-repository-metadata-repomd-xml-for-re) post with some possible fixes, one of which is updating to the latest CentOS. This [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/697752/yum-repo-responding-with-errno-14-http-error-403-forbidden) post also had an Errno 14 error message like you're seeing, but this solution was to disable SELinux.